# How do i sync files only in my p4 label?

Tags: perforce

I have a label that's a subset of a bigger tree and wondering if there is an option in p4 sync to update only the files that are part of the workspace. p4 sync @label usually deletes all other files that are not part of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
p4 sync @label,@label
```

Or:

```
p4 -F %depotFile%%depotRev% files @label | p4 -x - sync
```